# unity3d 4.3 facebook SDK login

Tags: facebook, facebook-unity-sdk

hi i have unity3d and the latest facebook sdk

i've downloaded the sample project but i got a problem, when i start the project and click login, unity immediately show this images:

[image]

which i expecting i've got an error from this part of code in mainmenu.cs

```
if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
    {
        string panelText = "Welcome ";


        if (GameStateManager.Username != null) panelText += GameStateManager.Username + "!";
        else panelText += "Smasher!"; //I GOT THIS ELSE BLOCK !

        if (GameStateManager.UserTexture != null) 
            GUI.DrawTexture( (new Rect(8,10, 150, 150)), GameStateManager.UserTexture);


        GUI.Label( (new Rect(179 , 11, 287, 160)), panelText, MenuSkin.GetStyle("text_only"));
    }
```

which is my gamestatemanager.username is null... i just want to know why my gamestatemanager.username is null, how to get some data to fill that.. i've followed step to fill gamestatemanager.username in this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/tutorials/games/personalize/) where's my error btw ? anyone can help ?

Comment: Did you put in your Facebook app id?  Also is this from within the Unity Editor?  There's no actual login from within the editor.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this question.  [Unity Facebook SDK Login Always Returns User 0 Access Token abc...z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20152140/unity-facebook-sdk-login-always-returns-user-0-access-token-abc-z/20153738#20153738) We don't support the editor or desktop yet.  You will have to run on an ios or android device, or publish your app to facebook canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having the same problem I am...
It seems it has logged you in but returns USerID:0 and Access Token: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

I think this is a TEST User that is automatically logs in but I can't seem to find out how to turn that off and to actually have it log ME on.

Is your APP in Sandbox mode?  I tried turning my sandbox mode in the facebook app settings off  but it didn't seem to effect it...
Waiting for an answer on this and my related question...
[Unity Facebook SDK Login Always Returns User 0 Access Token abc...z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20152140/unity-facebook-sdk-login-always-returns-user-0-access-token-abc-z)

If you are running this from the EDITOR then the reason is the EDITOR does not actually log you in.

If you are running from the device...I am still working on that one (also getting the same result you are)

Comment: yep, im running in editor... i build it to webplayer and desktop .exe too... but unfortunately the "welcome smasher" and button like play and fullscreen dont even show! i don't really know how fb sdk works... btw have you been upload your webplayer test to some web server ?